# Do I publish a paper independently or ask a professor to mentor me?

Tags: publications, undergraduate, research-undergraduate, independent-researcher, review-articles

I am an undergraduate studentcurrently in my 3rd year. I have worked on a project for the last year. I was thinking of writing a review paper about the topic. It was a graded project in my curriculum and I had a mentor to guide me(for one semester, after that I have worked on it independently), except that my mentor was not interested at all in my work. (I got similar opinions about the said mentor from my classmates who were working with her) Should I go to her and ask for guidance related to writing the paper or should I go ahead and try to publish it independently?

Answer (score 6):

First, you should assure yourself, and then again, that the work is correct by the standards of your field. It is this point that requires insight into your topic. You know best by yourself whether you need a mentor or not.

Second, you need to 'sell' your work. This point does not require expertise in your particular niche, but it can benefit from knowledge of people in your discipline. This includes aspects such as Academic English, Writing an Abstract, Writing an Introduction, and so on. Maybe there are some trustworthy (!) persons in your discipline that could proofread it for you?

Comment: All of that is correct, but please *don't* go to the person that had no interest in your work the first time around. What will likely happen is that her name appears on your paper and you *still* don't get valuable advise.